# CSS Alignment - Stacking 2 images to the right of another

Tags: css

How do I place editInfoButton and hypChangePassword on top of each other but to the right of imgProfilePic ? All being centralised like this..

[image]

```
<h1>Central Title</h1>
<asp:Image ID="imgProfilePic" style="border: 4px solid black;" runat="server" width="120px" ImageUrl="" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="editInfoButton" runat="server" class="backNextButton" width="160px" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/editInfoButton.png" onClick="editInfoButton_Click" />
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypChangePassword" runat="server" class="backNextButton" width="160px" visible="true" NavigateUrl="~/account/changePassword.aspx" ><asp:Image ID="imgChangePassword" runat="server" style="width:160px;" ImageUrl="~/files/images/icons/changePasswordButton.png" /></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: You can use CSS grid or flexbox to do that.

Comment: Thanks Terry, Just tried both.. No luck. I'm quite new with CSS so unsure exactly what to do. As I adjust the size of one of the smaller ones, the large imgProfilePic one adjusts to same size.